# How to match item from two different databases based using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need a bit of guidance figuring out how to make two similar values in angular js from two different tables. The tables am using are a user table and a school table. So what I need to do is based on the logged in user I am supposed to get a school name related to that user but currently am not sure how to go about this. Any assistance in guiding me on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

School Service Controller Code:

```
    angular.module('starter').factory('Schools',['apiUrl','$resource', 'UserInfo', function(apiUrl,$resource, UserInfo){
    var factory = $resource(apiUrl + '/schools/:schoolId', 
    { 
        schoolId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'GET'
        }
    });

    return factory;
}]);
```

Profile Controller Code Snippet:

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers')

.controller('ProfileController', function($scope,$http,$state,Schools, $ionicPopup, apiUrl, UserInfo,$ionicLoading,$ionicHistory,Users,Authentication) {

    $scope.apiUrl = apiUrl;
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.state = $state;
    $scope.selected = {};

    var user = Authentication.user.school;

   $scope.find = function(queryParams){
    $scope.place = [];
    var user = $scope.authentication.user.school;
    var school = Schools.query({_id: user.school})

    var params = queryParams || {};
    params._id = user;

    Schools.query(params, function(response){
        if (params._id === school){
            // response.splice(0, $scope.place.lengh);
            // for(var x = 0; x< response.lengh; x++){
            //  $scope.place.push(response[x]);
            // }
            $scope.place = response[0].name;
        }
        else{
            $scope.place = response;
        }
    })
}

    $scope.signOut = function(){

        $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: "SIGN OUT",
            template: '<p align="center">' + 'PLEASE CONFIRM IF YOU WANT TO SIGN OUT'+ '</p>',
            buttons: [
            { text: "NO",
            type: 'button button-outline button-assertive',
            onTap:function(e){
                return false;
            }
        },
        {
            text: "YES",
            type:'button-positive',
            onTap:function(e){
            //now you can clear history or goto another state if you need
            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });

            $state.go('signin');
            return true;

        }
    }
    ]
});
    };
});
```

My value for "$scope.find function" is returned properly but is the whole list of school names and details rather than the one which matches the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is server side logic. When you pass logged in user to your api then do some database query based on that user in the server side and return json object with all the list of schools .

Comment: Yes, that's how it works so far. Am just mainly interacting with the prebuild controllers. Am still a bit new to angular so am trying to understand how will I loop through my data to find if the user table details matches the school table details in regards of the school name as currently the user table only shows the school table ID rather then the name.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured a way to get the correct values based on the id reference of school in the user table. I had to use the angularjs forEach method to first query the data then filter it in a if statement to get the results I was looking for.

Solution:

```
$scope.find = function(){
    var school = $scope.authentication.user.school;
    $scope.schoolName = Schools.query(function(results) {
        results.forEach(function(result) {
            if (result._id === school) {
                $scope.schoolName = result.name;
                return $scope.schoolName;
            }
        });
    });
}
```